# Getting error for differences in number of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I keep getting this error code "Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , x, value = c(16100, 14800, 13100,  : 
  replacement has 163 rows, data has 182" and I'm not sure how to fix this. I know it has something to do with NAs but i've tried na.omit and couldn't get it to work. I've tried changing the number of rows in the dischange.data matrix but that doesn't work either. Please help!

```
library(waterData)

## List of start dates
start.dates <- c(
                 "2009-12-01", "2010-12-01", "2011-12-01", "2012-12-01",
                 "2013-12-01", "2014-12-01", "2015-12-01", "2016-12-01",
                 "2017-12-01", "2018-12-01")


## List of end dates
end.dates <- c( 
               "2010-05-31", "2011-05-31", "2012-05-30", "2013-05-31", 
               "2014-05-31", "2015-05-31", "2016-05-30", "2017-05-31",
               "2018-05-31", "2019-05-31")

## Bind start and end dates into a single dataframe
flow.dates <- as.data.frame(cbind(start.dates, end.dates))

## Empty dataframe for discharge data; nrow=no of days in each inverval, 
#ncol=no invtervals
discharge.data <- as.data.frame(data.frame(matrix(0, 
                                                  nrow = 182, ncol = 10))) 

## Append data for all dates
for(x in 1:10){
  bin.1 <- importDVs(staid = "02198375", code = "00060", stat = "00003",
                     sdate = flow.dates[x, 1],
                     edate = flow.dates[x, 2])
  bin.2 <- cleanUp(bin.1, task = "fix", replace = 0.001)
  bin.3 <- fillMiss(bin.1, block = 2, pmiss = 5, model = "trend", 
                    smooth = FALSE, log = "y")
  bin.4 <- bin.3[, c(2, 3)]
  colnames(bin.4) <- c(flow.dates[x, 3])
  discharge.data[, x] <- bin.4[, 1]
}

## Calculate season mean & convert from ft3 to m3
mean.discharge.ws <- sapply(discharge.data, mean)
met.shift.ws <- (mean.discharge.ws / 35.315)

## Create dataframe

met.winterspring.Year <- c( 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014,
                           2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019)

df=data.frame(met.shift.ws, met.winterspring.Year)
my.formula = df$met.shift.ws ~ df$met.winterspring.Year

fit = lm(met.winterspring.Year ~  met.shift.ws ,data=df )
summary(fit)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc) # for dealing with stat equations
library (grid)

ggplot(df, aes(met.winterspring.Year, met.shift.ws)) +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x="", y=(expression(Discharge~(m^{3}~s^{-1}))))+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks_width(2)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 2017, y = 300, label = "Winter-Spring", hjust = "left")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what water.data is or what half of the functions do, but I quickly downloaded the package, and if you add `print(x)` in your for loop where you append data for all dates, you'll immediately see that for `x=7`, there are 163 rows in bin.1, and not 182. I don't know what that means, but if its just a think where 1:182 is just a to hold the values, then you can just pad some NAs if the length of the vectors you are appending are too small. So maybe something like

```
discharge.data <- as.data.frame(data.frame(matrix(0, 
                                                  nrow = 182, ncol = 10))) 

## Append data for all dates
for(x in 1:10){
  bin.1 <- importDVs(staid = "02198375", code = "00060", stat = "00003",
                     sdate = flow.dates[x, 1],
                     edate = flow.dates[x, 2])
  bin.2 <- cleanUp(bin.1, task = "fix", replace = 0.001)
  bin.3 <- fillMiss(bin.1, block = 2, pmiss = 5, model = "trend", 
                    smooth = FALSE, log = "y")
  bin.4 <- bin.3[, c(2, 3)]
  colnames(bin.4) <- c(flow.dates[x, 3])

  #pad some NAs if too short vector 
  vec = bin.4[,1]
  len = length(vec)
  if (len < 182) {
    vec = c(vec,rep(NA,182-len))
  }

  discharge.data[, x] <- vec
}
```

This should work. If the data.frame you want to append to has some more conditions that I don't understand, then you should probably use `merge`..